# mongo aggregate function is not working with socket io

Tags: mongodb, express, socket.io

Hi I am trying to run MongoDB queries inside socket io functions.findOne is working correctly but find and aggregate functions are not working at all.enter code here

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function (err, client) {
    const db = client.db('dbName');

    const bookWalker = db.collection('bookwalkers');
    const walker = db.collection('walkers');


    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('enterRoom', function (data) {
            socket.room = data.room;
            socket.join(data.room);
            console.log("connected to room", data.room);

            bookWalker.find({"pendingWalk._id":
                   ObjectId("5bd994d2f395622e0b8f71af")},async function(err,resp)  {
                       console.log("dataf",resp);
                       io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('getStartTime', resp[0]);
             });
       });
 });
```

});

this is Sample data in DB

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5bd994d2f395622e0b8f71ad"),
"pendingWalk" : [ 
    {
        "walkPicture" : [],
        "status" : 0,
        "walkPath" : [],
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bd994d2f395622e0b8f71af"),
        "bookedDate" : ISODate("2018-10-31T13:30:56.581Z"),
        "bookedTime" : ""
    }
],
"userId" : ObjectId("5b6e932062bce05ae5647980"),
"book_dt" : ISODate("2018-10-31T11:41:06.230Z"),
"__v" : 0}
```

the query is working fine inside mongo shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongodb find() returns a cursor not array. You have to call toArray() function.

```
    bookWalker.find({"pendingWalk._id":ObjectId("5bd994d2f395622e0b8f71af")}).toArray(function(err,resp){
     console.log(resp[0]);
});
```